# Box2d performance issue

Tags: box2d, physics, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using Box2d with cocos2dx. I am creating a dynamic body on each frame, and after creating 150 dynamic bodies the game performances decrease. Here is the code I use to do this:

```
Settings()
{
    viewCenter.Set(0.0f, 20.0f);
    hz = 10.0f;
    velocityIterations = 8;
    positionIterations = 3;
    drawShapes = 1;
    drawJoints = 1;
    drawAABBs = 0;
    drawContactPoints = 0;
    drawContactNormals = 0;
    drawContactImpulse = 0;
    drawFrictionImpulse = 0;
    drawCOMs = 0;
    drawStats = 0;
    drawProfile = 0;
    enableWarmStarting = 1;
    enableContinuous = 1;
    enableSubStepping = 0;
    enableSleep = 1;
    pause = 0;
    singleStep = 0;
}

class Tumbler : public Test
{
public:

    enum
    {
        e_count = 800
    };

    Tumbler()
    {
        b2BodyDef bd;
        bd.allowSleep = true;
        bd.gravityScale = 9.8;
        ground = m_world->CreateBody(&bd);
        m_count = 0;
        m_count_obj = 0;


        bd2.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        bd2.allowSleep = true;
        bd2.gravityScale = 9.8f;
        bd2.position.Set(512,600);

        shape_.m_p.Set(0,0);
        shape_.m_radius = 4;
        body = NULL;
    }

    void Step(Settings* settings,cocos2d::Sprite* data)
    {
        Test::Step(settings,data);

        if (m_count_obj<=e_count && 0 == (m_count%15))
        {

            m_count_obj++;

            body = m_world->CreateBody(&bd2);
            body->SetUserData(data);
            body->SetBullet(false);
            body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(150,1500));
            body->CreateFixture(&shape_, 1.0f);

        }

        ++m_count;
    }

    static Test* Create()
    {
        return new Tumbler;
    }

    b2Body* ground = NULL;
    int32 m_count;
    int32 m_count_obj;
    b2EdgeShape shape;
    b2BodyDef bd2;
    b2CircleShape shape_;
    b2Body* body;
};
```

I need to create approx 3000 dynamic bodies. I got this code from cocos2dx example.

Comment: Well you can't create so many dynamic bodies.

Comment: well i have also try following : if count of dynamic body is greater then 30 then i have remove first index body from world and add another i.e  only 30 dynamic body will be in world at same time but here also facing same problem after 150 bodys.

Comment: You create all the dynamic bodies with the same initial position, which slows down Box2D (see Box2D manual). Have you tried to give them different positions, so that they don't initially overlap?

Comment: How much does the game performance decrease? At what rate does it decrease? Does the decrease seem linearly related to the number of bodies? Do you always notice the performance loss? Performance will decrease the more bodies interact with each other so some decrease is expected.